# Customizing Azure AD B2C login page

Tags: azure, customization, azure-ad-b2c

I have followed the docs on microsoft page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-customize-ui. I have created the customization files `custom-ui.html` and `styles.css` they show in the documentation, but when I change the style in `styles.css`, the changes doesn't appear, even though I have added the link in the field where the URI to the custom content (HTML/CSS) for the page is hosted. And when I tried to change the style I also used incognito browser, because of cookies.

Is anyone able to help me? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the browser cache, we need to clean it up. And even in private mode, if you change the file but the page doesn't show up, you still need to refresh to show the changed page.